# Send left square bracket using autoit

Tags: windows, autoit

I have plugged a Mac French keyboard onto Windows.

I would like to have the left bracket key work normally, meaning when typing Alt+Shift+(, even with left hand side modifiers.

I have the following code :

```
HotKeySet("!+{(}", "LeftBracket")

 Func LeftBracket()
      Send("{ASC 91}")
 EndFunc
```

But it doesn't work.

When I replace the hotkey by `"!a"`, it works. 
When I replace `Send("{ASC 91}")` by `Send("a")` it sends `a` correctly.

But it seems not to work when I have the code above.

Comment: I don't know what the mac keyboard looks like, but on mine I'd have to use "!+9" to get this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this is a French layout keyboard. I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of these possibilities. ( needs already the shift key :-)

```
HotKeySet("!{(}", "LeftBracket")
HotKeySet("!+{9}", "LeftBracket1")

while 1
    Sleep(1000)
Wend

 Func LeftBracket()
      Send("{ASC 91}" & 'HUHU')
 EndFunc

  Func LeftBracket1()
      Send("{ASC 91}" & 'BLA')
 EndFunc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I am not sure I understand the purpose of "HUHU". Won't it show ?

Comment: It will be send to the active window.

Comment: Well then I don't see how that could work. I can't have "HUHU" typed when I try to type [

Comment: By the way, I tested it, and the result is that it displays "UHU", not "HUHU", and not "[HUHU". This is weird, isn't it ?

Comment: Maybe you problem is that SHIFT+ALT alters the keboard language.